Decomposition of $[0,1]$ where Banach-Tarski fails
In a comment below this question on Banach-Tarski "paradoxon"
@Asaf Karagila made following interesting comment:

And a universe where the Banach-Tarski fails you can take a stick of length $[0,1]$ and divide it into more parts than it has points [...].

Could somebody elaborate / provide background / links discussing this statement rigurously & presenting involved construction behind?

Define an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$ by saying "$x\sim y\leftrightarrow x-y$ is rational". It is consistent with ZF (the usual axioms of set theory  minus the axiom of choice) that $\sim$ has more equivalence classes than the cardinal of the continuum. This weird property holds in any model of ZF where all sets of real numbers are Lebessgue measurable.

Does this have to do with forcing/sheaf models?

@AndreasBlass: I not completely got the part why there are more equivalence classes wrt  this partition $\sim$ than the cardinal of continuum assuming that BT is wrong?

@NaïmFavier Yes. The construction of models where all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable is a two-step process. The first step is a forcing extension (of the universe or of a model of ZFC); the second is forming an inner model within that forcing extension.

@user267839 The assumption that all sets of reals  are Lebesgue measurable is stronger than  just the negation of BT. The proof that it implies that weird partition property is not easy to see. It depends on Kolmogorov's zero-one law. I first learned this proof from Mycielski's paper  "The axiom of determinateness," but there may be earlier sources.

@AndreasBlass: ah, so just to clarify if I understood your point correctly: So above you suggest that partitioning $[0,1]$
via $\sim$
declared as above indeed does the job - namely that there are more equiv classes then the cardinality of $ [0,1]$
assuming we are working in any model of ZF where all sets of reals are measurable. But how to see it precisely that in this example indeed the eq classes wrt $\sim$
as you defined partition $[0,1]$ indeed this weird way is non trivial, so you state it in the prev comment as black box, right?

... the point is that in Mycielski's paper this example seemingly not explicitly appear

Looking back at Mycielski's paper, I agree that the example isn't explicit there. To see that it's implicit, first see the definition of $\mathfrak k$ at the bottom of page 208 and assertion (vii) on page 209. Then see item 2 on page 220 (in particular the last paragraph, about using measure instead of Baire category). Then see  item 7 on page 222 for the connection between “not linearly orderable” and “bigger than the continuum.” Finally, the Remark just before item 8 on the same page points out that $\mathfrak k$ is also the number of equivalence classes of the $\sim$ that I defined.
